# Ninject, Parallel.ForEach and InThreadScope()

Tags: c#, multithreading, inversion-of-control, ninject

I would appreciate suggestions as to how to implement the following with Ninject:

I have a multi-threaded application.  It runs approximately 20 very independent threads concurrently.  Upon the application startup, I bind an interface to an object via Ninject by using InThreadScope() and all works well.  Each thread receives object specific to its thread (constructor of each object instantiates a number of thread-specific flags).

Most of the work that each thread does, is waiting for data-storage to finish process.  So, in order to optimize the threads even further, we've implemented Parallel.ForEach logic inside the main 20 threads.  I would like for threads generated by Paralell.ForEach to get the same binding as their parent thread.  However, I cannot simply re-bind the interface to appropriate object inside the Parallel.ForEach, I simply do not know what the bound object is - inside Paralell.ForEach I can only work with the interface.

What's the proper way to retrieve bindings from the Kernel at runtime, before Paralell.ForEach starts and re-bind them generically inside the loop?

**Edit: attempting to include detailed logic/pseudocode:**

Each thread once started does something like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<ILoggingContext>().To<Application1LoggingContext>().InThreadScope();
```

However, when Parallel.ForEach() kicks in, from inside the individual threads, I no longer have access to Application1LoggingContext object and cannot rebind the ILoggingContext to it.  This is because the Parallel.ForEach() is running from a base class and knows not what Application LoggingContext it needs to be bound to. That is done inside each application, upon starting of the big 20 threads.

I'd like to modify the base class, the one that spins up Parallel.ForEach() and ensure inside of each newly created by Parallel.ForEach thread, that ILoggingContext is still bound to Application1LoggingContext - generically, so that I can perform the following:

```
var ctx = Kernel.Get<ILoggingContext>();
```

Comment: Could you please post sample code (pseudocode) of how you would like to use Paralell.ForEach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've figured this out.  Here is a generic way to rebind a binding inside Parallel.Foreach.  Depending on the complexity/number of bindings, this may or may not work for you out of the box

```
var logBinding = Kernel.GetBindings(typeof(ILoggingContext)).FirstOrDefault();

Parallel.ForEach(items, n =>
                            {
                                if (Kernel.GetBindings(typeof(ILoggingContext)).Count() == 0 && logBinding != null)
                                    Kernel.AddBinding(logBinding);

                                //do stuff
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you capture the ILoggingContext in a closure to pass to the Parallel.ForEach() iterations?

Your base class method (`StartUpBase.Start()`) that kicks off the Parallel.ForEach() can be called from a context-aware derived type (`StartUpApplication1`) on the parent thread. The derived type can acquire the `ILoggingContext` from the Ninject kernel that you want to pass to the children and pass that to the base class method, which then passes it into the parallel iterations via a closure: e.g:

```
abstract class StartUpBase
{
    public abstract void Start();

    protected void StartApplication<T>(ILoggingContext ctx, IEnumerable<T> enumerableWork)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(enumerableWork, iter =>
            {
                // this code can refer to ctx e.g.
                ctx.Log(message);
            });
    }
}

internal class StartupApplication1<T> : StartUpBase
{
    // setup of this is elsewhere...
    private IEnumerable<T> _enumerableWork;

    public override void Start()
    {
        ILoggingContext ctx = Kernel.Bind<ILoggingContext>()
            .To<Application1LoggingContext>().InThreadScope();
        StartApplication(ctx, _enumerableWork);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.  Unfortunately, the code inside Parallel.ForEach is doing a Kernel.Get<ILoggingContext>() and it must continue doing so

Comment: Well then logically, if you are insisting on using the Kernel to get the ILoggingContext from within the iterations you will have to use something other than InThreadScope, like a custom provider. Sounds like you are making your life quite complicated! Posting more of your code will probably help you get a better answer.

Comment: The code is quiet complex.  I was hoping to be able to iterate through the Bindings collection inside Kernel in some way to re-bind the ILoggingContext in a generic way.

Comment: Ideally, it's only your "composition root" (ref: Mark Seemann) that should have any knowledge of your IoC container anyway... in this case the "parent thread" seems to fulfil the role of composition root - perhaps you could review whether your child threads need to be aware of the Ninject kernel?